# Filling the region under a line

Tags: plotting, filling

I have the following straight line:

```
y[x_] = 4 x - 1;
Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}]
```

I want to highlight the two regions separated by the straight line, such that they look nice and distinct.

Answer (score 8):

```
y[x_] := 4 x - 1;
Plot[{y[x], y[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {Top, LightYellow}, 2 -> {Bottom, LightBlue}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The coolest ideas are often simple (when you know them ;-) )

Comment: thank you @mgamer.

Answer (score 2):

One can also use `InfiniteLine[]` and `HalfPlane[]` for this:

```
Graphics[{{LightYellow, HalfPlane[{0, -1}, {1, 4}, Cross[{1, 4}]]},
          {LightBlue, HalfPlane[{0, -1}, {1, 4}, -Cross[{1, 4}]]},
          {Blue, InfiniteLine[{0, -1}, {1, 4}]}},
         AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image: regions]